# If statement is always run even if not true

Tags: python, power-management

I want to set a powercap when the system uses more than 400 Watt. I tried to do to do that with a simple if statement but the if statement is also run when the current power is 256 Watt

My code looks like this

```py
a=400

node1 = Node(0, 0, 0, 0)
node1.getPowerUsage()
node1.getGpuPowerUsage()
node1.getCpuPowerUsage()
node1.setPowercap()


if(node1.getCpuPowerUsage() > a):
    node1.setPowercap()

else:
    print("nothing to do")
```

The output of the `node1.getCpuPowerUsage()` looks like this

```
print node1.getCpuPowerUsage()
277.54
```

I exepct to see an output like this when ist under 400 Watt
`nothing to do`
But actually i get this output
`Current Power     : 247 Watts`

```
Enabled persistence mode for GPU 00000000:35:00.0.
Enabled persistence mode for GPU 00000000:5B:00.0.
Enabled persistence mode for GPU 00000000:CD:00.0.
Enabled persistence mode for GPU 00000000:AA:00.0.
All done.
Power limit for GPU 00000000:35:00.0 was set to 125.00 W from 250.00 W.
Power limit for GPU 00000000:5B:00.0 was set to 125.00 W from 250.00 W.
Power limit for GPU 00000000:CD:00.0 was set to 125.00 W from 250.00 W.
Power limit for GPU 00000000:AA:00.0 was set to 125.00 W from 250.00 W.
All done.
nothing to do
```

Or have you other suggestions how i could do it?

Comment: If the value is indeed the float value `277.54`, then this should work just fine as expected. The problem can't be deduced from this sample code.

Comment: See what the *actual* value is with `print repr(node1.getCpuPowerUsage())`. Is it a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the value to float.

**Ex:**

```
a=400

node1 = Node(0, 0, 0, 0)
node1.getPowerUsage()
node1.getGpuPowerUsage()
node1.getCpuPowerUsage()
node1.setPowercap()


if(float(node1.getCpuPowerUsage()) > a):
    node1.setPowercap()
else:
    print("nothing to do")
```

Comment: that worked but i had to remove the node1.setPowercap() before the if statement